# TypeScript Intellisense on package.json "exports"

Tags: typescript, npm, import, package, package.json

I think there's something wrong with my simple TypeScript setup for a workspace utils package I'm creating. When I install and import the package the imports work, and the typesafety is all there. However, Intellisense won't give me hints about the available `"exports"`. There's only a red squiggly line that disappears once I've typed the right path.

Here's the `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "@app/utils",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc -w",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "exports": {
    "./numbers": {
      "import": {
        "types": "./dist/types/numbers.d.ts",
        "default": "./dist/numbers.js"
      }
    },
    "./datetime": {
      "import": {
        "types": "./dist/types/datetime.d.ts",
        "default": "./dist/datetime.js"
      }
    }
  },
  "types": "./dist/types",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

And here's the `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "noEmit": false,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist/types",
    "resolvePackageJsonExports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "bundler"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

The last two entries in `compilerOptions` don't really change anything. Is this a setup problem or is there nothing wrong with this setup?

Comment: Hi. Did you figure this out? I am struggling with the same exact thing. I get Intellisense when using barrel files (i.e. `import { Button } from "@acme/ui";`, but not if trying to import from a subfolder: `import Button from "@acme/ui/button";`